# Firemonkey android app pixel RGB values are slightly off?

Tags: android, delphi, rgb, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I need to be able to control the RGB values of the pixels on an android tablet using Delphi XE5 (update 2). It is possible to set pixel values using the SetPixel procedure. However, at close inspection, the pixel values of a bitmap can be slightly off. For example, with a single TImage on the form and the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var vBitMapData  : TBitmapData;
    x,y: Integer;
begin
  Image1.WrapMode := TImageWrapMode.iwOriginal;
  Image1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(125,125);
  if  image1.Bitmap.Map(TMapAccess.maReadWrite, vBitMapData) then
  for y := 0 to Image1.Bitmap.Height-1 do
  begin
    for x := 0 to Image1.Bitmap.Width-1 do
    begin
      if odd(x) then vBitMapData.SetPixel(x,y,claWhite)
                else vBitMapData.SetPixel(x,y,claBlack);
    end;
  end;
  image1.Bitmap.Unmap(vBitMapData);
end;
```

a black and white grating appears on the tablet (I am using a Nexus 10), but after making a screenshot using the power and volume down button and e-mailing the resulting png to my windows pc, the grating appears to have not only RGB values of (0,0,0) and (255,255,255), but also (1,1,1) and (254,254,254).

Does anyone know why I do not get all true black and white stripes? As I understand png is lossless and also running the same program on Win32 produces the correct result, so it seems to be something specifically related to the android implementation.

Any suggestion or workaround to what is going on would be great.

---

### Example problematic bitmaps:

Original (1px) [image] 5 pixel test
[image]

Comment: Did you try dumping your image directly?

Comment: Usually that is called "antialiasing" and frequently done when image is zoomed or rescaled from virtual coordinates of software to physical ones of hardware. I suspect FMX does this but maybe Android if your application has non-native window size. Anyway,  "antialiasing" is the word to Google

Comment: Add the picture to your question (enlarged maybe)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
@FreeConsulting: Yes, I did try placing an image made on the pc directly in the TImage, but get the same result.

Comment: @Arioch: It does not seem to be an issue of antialiasing. The ImageWrapMode is set to iwOriginal. Also, if the DisableInterpolation property is set to true, the result stays the same.

Comment: @JanDoggen: Somehow I can't add pictures. The picture is very simple though, just a bitmap of 125x125 pixels somewhere of black and white vertical lines of one pixel wide. The problem is though that some lines are not exactly white and black.

Comment: @user2297042, I'd try to generate 5px wide and verify if pixels in question appear along black-white border only.

Comment: Another idea is to draw thick bands not orthogonal and not 45 degrees, but (arctan 2) skew (2 to 1 ratio of delta-Y and delta-X). Or 3 to 1. Or 10 to 1, etc. That way, if it is antialiasing, it should blend from black to white gradually.

Comment: @user2297042 You can upload your pic somewhere else and include the link (e.g. at imgur). Another user will edit it into the question for you.

Comment: Ok, the original image can be found at: http://imgur.com/FEtoYr5&B8VnBuW, a second image with 5 pixel wide stripes odd(x div 5) in the code) can be found at: http://imgur.com/FEtoYr5&B8VnBuW#1

Comment: @FreeConsulting: With the 5 pixel wide stripes the effect indeed only shows on some of the borders. Any idea what causes this and how to avoid them?

Comment: @Arioch'The: I changed the code to odd(x +(y div 2)), which gives the following picture: http://imgur.com/SknX3rQ. This still gives pixel values 1 and 254, sometimes even 253 now. Note, that it may not be exactly what your suggestion was, but I am setting the color of pixels, not drawing lines or shapes.

Comment: @user2297042, then this effect definitely caused by smoothing (interpolation "blended" a bit of white from the adjacent pixels into your black and a bit of black into white).

Comment: I slightly remember FMX used its own float point coordinates, at least FMX 3D, then some jitter would be almost inevitable due to non-exact nature of floating point. Or maybe there is some shader effect applied to the whole form or control

Comment: It indeed seems there is some bleeding. However, this only happens with the Android as the target platform, not with Win32. I think this rules out a possible floating point issue (the bitmap coordinates are also Integers). Do any of you know if Android has options to turn of the shading/blending that seems to be causing this effect?

Comment: To rule out whatever possible effect applied on Android, I'd try to generate off-screen bitmap, dump it to file and check if problem persists. Its important to ensure no transforms applied. Disclaimer: I know a things about image processing but nothing about Firedonkey and/or Android.

Comment: With debugging, I can see that the RGB values of the bitmap of the TImage stays correct.  So, it must be the way it is painted on the screen. Or, the screenshot function of Android is not true loss-less (even though a png image supposedly is)?

Comment: @Arioch There is no jitter